# Timelapse app suggestion for android

Tags: gratis, android, photography

I am looking for an android app which would support following needs for generating time lapse videos:

- working with screen off (to save energy)
- resolution higher or 1080p
- picture interval 5 sec or less
- free to use (lite version)

Nice to have would be a fully free app, and self generating a movie from the frames at the end.

Right now I do use 24/7 Time Lapse Lite which meets the spec above, but a 5sec interval is too big.

Alternative apps usually needs to be active (screen).

Answer (score 2):

[Framelapse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Nishant.Singh.DroidTimelapse) freely allows variable intervals of 0.1 seconds to 10 minutes and records a movie you can replay.  Unfortunately, the current version holds the screen on, but you could dial down the brightness, or ask the developer about a dark screen version.

Comment: It seems to me  that Framelapse runs only on Android < v10,  and Framlapse Pro for Android v10+. This is what the Play Store offered me for installation.

Comment: It may be possible to use the following app to turn off the screen while Framelapse runs: https://f-droid.org/en/packages/android.jonas.fakestandby/